# How do I create a link on my desktop for opening Internet Explorer with multiple tabs?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, browser-tabs

I use a web application which is based on multiple tabs in browser. This is all fine to me, since this means I can just load those tabs to a single browser instance and have them there in one big group. However I'd like to be able to *persist* those tabs since reopening them is a bit cumbersome. Since I'm using Internet Explorer 9, I already tried the new [pinning sites feature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/stevecla01/pinning-sites-in-ie9) but that only allows for a single tab to be pinned.

So, how do I create a link similar to pinned site that would spawn a new instance of Internet Explorer 9 with the tabs I have predefined?

Comment: Is IE your default browser? I assume that you don't want to set this web app as your home page(s) - it would be the easiest way to open several tabs.

Comment: @Siim: IE is currently not my default browser, although it might be in the future. And no, I'd like to reserve the home page functionality for other stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tony Schreiner has blogged about a way to launch IE and open several additional tabs (that have not been set as home pages) via the command line.  Basically you create a JS file, and launch IE using that file using Windows Scripting Host.

You can find information about how to do that here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/tonyschr/archive/2007/01/19/ie-automation-amp-tabs.aspx

Hope I could help

Comment: This nearly did what I wanted, the only problem now is that the web-app I mentioned in my question apparently uses some heavy JavaScript hijinx to fit itself to the browser window so that it fails when launched this way. That's of course the web-app's problem so this is really what I wanted.